# Rally app SDK 2.0rc1 - Uncaught ReferenceError: rally is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Long time SO reader, first time questioner. I'm fairly new to coding in JavaScript and I'm working on a Rally app. I'm trying to "update" existing items, so I figured I'd set up the datasource at the beginning of the app, like this:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        this.rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__",
                 "__PROJECT_OID__",
                 "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__",
                 "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
```

However, on page load, the Chrome console is showing me "Uncaught ReferenceError: rally is not defined". I checked the HTML to ensure there was a reference to sdk.js, and there is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
```

I've searched around and attempted some solutions, but nothing seems to work. Any one else run into this or know what it causing it?

Edit: To clarify, I am testing this within the Rally workspace in which it will be used. I have comboboxes correctly loading and populating with Release and User Story info, so I know it is able to communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rixo is on the right track above.  Basically, you're trying to use sdk 1.x code (rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource and the hangman variables) from the sdk 2.x.

SDK 1.x is deprecated but the docs are still available here: https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk

SDK 2.x is the preferred platform and its docs are here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/

Both of those resources contain a bunch of guides for getting started and whatnot.

Comment: Well, I was using the docs, but seem to have gotten mixed up somewhere.

Although I'm still not sure how to update a specific record in the 2.0 SDK, I did find the BulkRecordUpdater, and this suited what I needed anyways.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out this guide, which explains models and demonstrates a full crud lifecycle: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/data_models

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Not sure how I missed it, but thank you for the direct link.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `Rally.sdk.data` with a capital 'r'?